# deserialization of a json array to a list and retaining the array order from json within list

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I have the following json that is mapped to a POJO using Jackson mapper. How do I retain the order of array columns from json during deserialization ? What annotation should I use ?

JSON:

```
{
"columnNames": [
   "FirstName",
   "LastName",
   "UserName"
],
"values": [
    [
        "John",
        "Smith",
        "jsmith"
    ],
    [
        "Tim",
        "Cook",
        "tcook"
    ]
]
```

}

POJO:

```
public class Data implements Serializable {

private List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

private List<ArrayList<String>> values = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

public List<String> getColumnNames() {
    return columnNames;
}

public void setColumnNames(List<String> columnNames) {
    this.columnNames = columnNames;
}

public List<ArrayList<String>> getValues() {
    return values;
}

public void setValues(List<ArrayList<String>> values) {
    this.values = values;
}
```

}

- Expected getColumnNames(): {"FirstName","LastName","UserName"}
- Actual getColumnNames():   {"UserName","FirstName","LastName"}

I am new to Jackson mapping so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your deserializer look like? It seems like you may simply be getting  deserializing in the wrong order. It might also be that the JSON isn't in the order you are expecting.

Comment: Hmmm, then either the JSON is out of order, or their implementation of `readValue` has the side effect of not always remaining in order. Clearly you do need them to remain in order, but aside from writing a custom deserializer, I don't think there's a way to overcome this. I used the GSON library for my deserialization and it was pretty easy to write deserializers. Not really sure if you have the option of trying a different library (it depends how much code you've written)

Comment: I checked it also and for me `Jackson` deserialize it as you expect. Do you use any custom deserializer or something like that? Maybe you, accidentally, are changing order in this list after deserializing, are n't you?

Comment: This was a misunderstanding in my end. Order is always retained during array deserialization which is the concept that drives ObjectMapper. According to this [blog](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_153.html), ObjectMapper implements a Tree Model to represent the incoming Json. Tree Model, like DOM, offers reliable one on one mapping between column and its values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson mapper fill the ArrayList maintaining the order of JSON. If you want a different order you can use the annotation @JsonPropertyOrder.

(https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html)