# Why Jackson deserialize json could not print object array in sequence?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

pojo class: Function.java

```
public class Function{

private Integer id;

private Set<MenuToFunction> menuToFunctions;

public Integer getId(){
return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id){
this.id=id;
}

public Set<MenuToFunction> getMenuToFunctions(){
return this.menuToFunctions;
}

    public void setMenuToFunctions(Set<MenuToFunction> menuToFunctions){
    this.menuToFunctions=menuToFunctions;
    }
}
```

pojo class: MenuToFunction.java

```
public class MenuToFunction{

    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId(){
    return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id){
    this.id=id;
    }
}
```

my json file, notice those ids are from 1 to 6.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "menuToFunctions": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

and finally, my test code. I use jackson and gson to deserialize json.

```
public class ReadJsonFile{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        String fileAbsolutePath="T:/GetFunctionDetailResponse.json";

        Function function=new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File(fileAbsolutePath),Function.class);

        for(MenuToFunction menuToFunction:function.getMenuToFunctions()){

        System.out.println("menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:"+menuToFunction.getId());
        }

        function=new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(new FileReader(fileAbsolutePath),Function.class);

        for(MenuToFunction menuToFunction:function.getMenuToFunctions()){

        System.out.println("menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:"+menuToFunction.getId());
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

console output

```
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:5
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:3
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:6
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:2
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:4
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:1
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:1
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:2
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:3
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:4
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:5
menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:6
```

So why Jackson deserialize json could not print object array in sequence, **but gson could**?

Are there any configure for Jackson?

I have aslo tried latest version jackson-2.10.3, but still have the same problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623126/deserialization-of-a-json-array-to-a-list-and-retaining-the-array-order-from-jso

Answer (score 0):

There is this property that could help: (from jackson's [documentation.](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html))

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "menuToFunctions" })
public class Function{

private Integer id;

private Set<MenuToFunction> menuToFunctions;

public Integer getId(){
return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id){
this.id=id;
}

public Set<MenuToFunction> getMenuToFunctions(){
return this.menuToFunctions;
}

    public void setMenuToFunctions(Set<MenuToFunction> menuToFunctions){
    this.menuToFunctions=menuToFunctions;
    }
}
```

Also include ordering in the ObjectMapper:

```
public class ReadJsonFile{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        String fileAbsolutePath="T:/GetFunctionDetailResponse.json";

        Function function=new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true)
            .configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true)
.readValue(new File(fileAbsolutePath),Function.class);

        for(MenuToFunction menuToFunction:function.getMenuToFunctions()){

        System.out.println("menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with jackson:"+menuToFunction.getId());
        }

        function=new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(new FileReader(fileAbsolutePath),Function.class);

        for(MenuToFunction menuToFunction:function.getMenuToFunctions()){

        System.out.println("menuToFunction.getMenu().getId() with gson:"+menuToFunction.getId());
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @Dennis Murage. But after I apply those configure, those ids are still not in sequence. I think this is json array problem, but not json properties problem.